# Whenever I build my project in unity, it doesn't work properly but the editor does

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial by @b3agz in youtube on how to code a game like minecraft in unity. My game works perfectly fine in the unity editor but then when i build the game it all works horribly wrong! I have found some lines of code that seem to be causing the issue. Here they are in my Start() function :

```
string jsonExport = JsonUtility.ToJson(settings);

File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Scripts/Minecraft/settings.cfg", jsonExport);

string jsonImport = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Scripts/Minecraft/settings.cfg");
settings = JsonUtility.FromJson<Settings>(jsonImport);
```

If I comment them out, the build works fine, can anyone see anything wrong here? If so please notify me as soon as you can. Thanks.

Comment: The project file structure does not exist once built so loading a json fole from /scripts will work in the ide but not outside

Comment: Any ideas what to do then?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html), which is not a good idea to be used in the build. Especially for saving data.

Use [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead.

Comment: I'll check to see if it works now, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, thanks for trying though.

Comment: What error do you have in the build and how your "build does not work properly" looks like?

Comment: i have mesh generation in it and the meshes aren't working so it's just a blank scene with a player in the middle of the void

Comment: So what error in the console do you see?

Comment: it is built, there are no console in builds that i know of.

Comment: You moved your data to the appropriate path right?  You can debug from the build by turning on Development Build & Script Debugging checkboxes in the build settings menu.

Comment: when i move my data to the Application.persistentDataPath, the editor doesn't work either and neither does the build. Where is the build settings menu?